# Reactjs FastApi - Get azure blob image?

Tags: reactjs, azure-blob-storage, fastapi

I have a developed a Reactjs front end, FastAPI backend and MongoDb database. I want to upload images to a private Azure storage account and consume them on the site.

What I'm struggling to understand is what the best practice is for loading the images?

Should I:

- Get a SAS key from my API, then go directly from Reactjs to the storage account URL?
- Get the image from the Azure storage using the API and serve it to the Reactjs
- A better option?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred way would be to go with option 1 - Get a SAS key from my API, then go directly from Reactjs to the storage account URL.

The advantages of this approach is that the Browser is directly requesting the images from Azure Storage so that there is less load on your API to fetch and serve the images. You may need to configure CORS settings on your Storage account if your React app is making an Ajax request to fetch the blob contents from Storage.

Doing this way however exposes your SAS URL to the client. If you do not want the clients to know from where the images are being served, then go with option 2.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav really useful. I would prefer to keep the SAS token private. I'm currently looking at whether I could generate a new one with each request?

Comment: You certainly can generate a new token with each request. Keep your tokens active for short durations and enforce IP ACLing if needed.